# Angular model change not reflected to CSS inline style

Tags: angularjs

Here is a clickable div. Once it clicked, it's supposed to change its position (defined by an inline CSS rule). The callback function is successfully invoked.

Problem: model change does not affect the inline CSS. Although initial values works well.

View:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items"
     data-ng-click="item.clicked()"
     data-ng-style="{'left': '{{item.left}}', 'width': '{{item.width}}', 'top': '0' }">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var item = {
    left: '30%',
    width: '20%'
};

(function(item) { // because inside a loop
    item.clicked = function() {
        console.log("item clicked");
        item.width = '100%';
        item.left = '0%';
    };
})(item);

$scope.items.push(item);
```

Angular 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't need the extra `{{`

```
data-ng-style="{'left': item.left, 'width': item.width, 'top': '0' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation of **ng-style**

**Known Issues:**
You should not use [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) in the value of the style attribute, when using the ngStyle directive on the same element. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues) for more info.

**Example how to use**

```
<input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<input type="button" value="set background" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'blue'}">
<input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
<br/>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
<pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
```